# In Google Cloud Spanner, can I update or delete by a non-Primary Key field?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

In Cloud Spanner SQL, it seems I can only perform an UPDATE or DELETE operation by Primary Key.  Even the API methods for these two operations have an argument that specifically requires a list of PK values to work on. 
In such an operation, can't I use criteria based off a non-PK field?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Sorry, all UPDATE and DELETE operations must involve the Primary Key of the table they are affecting.

It might be a bit of a kludge, but what you can do instead is to get a list of PK values from a SELECT statement (which does let your WHERE clause use a non-PK field), and pass that list of PK values to the UPDATE or DELETE operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Statement{}` with `ReadWriteTransaction()` for your purpose.

```
spannerClient.ReadWriteTransaction(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, txn *spanner.ReadWriteTransaction) error {
        rowCount, err := txn.Update(ctx, spanner.Statement{
            SQL: "update TABLE_NAME set UPDATE_COLUME=UPDATE_VALUE where CONDITION_COLUMN = @CONDITION_COLUMN",
            Params: map[string]interface{}{
                "CONDITION_COLUMN":  "CONDITION_VALUE",
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if rowCount == 0 {
            return errors.New("no such record")
        }
})
```